# How to get the position of a different object in gdscript?

Tags: position, nodes, scene, godot, gdscript

I have a player, and I want to be able to detect when they are near a ball so they can press 'E' to kick it.

I'm new to godot and I'm probably just dumb but I can't figure out how to get the position of another object.

I have 3 separate scenes: MainScene(Node2D), Player(KinematicBody2D), and Ball(RigidBody2D). I want to attach a script to one of the scenes that detects how close the Player is to the Ball so they can kick it.

I'm not sure if I should attach the script to the MainScene, the Player scene, or the Ball scene and to be honest, I'm not entirely sure how the code should look. I'm not very familiar with the functions and the node/scene hierarchy is a little confusing.

I am familiar with Python, I just think I'm overwhelmed with this engine (its my first time using a game engine) and I'm having a bit of a tough time grasping it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Side-quest: If you are feeling extra helpful I also need to figure out how to stop a RigidBody2D object from moving until the player hits 'E' on it to kick it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you want an `Area2D`, which is purpose-built for "detecting nearby objects" without interacting with them physics-wise. Have an `Area2D` as a child of the Player node and connect the Player node to that `Area2D`'s `body_entered` signal. [Here's a tutorial on using Area2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/tutorials/physics/using_area_2d.html) for further info; this tutorial also links to various other tutorials that could be helpful.

Comment: Man I've tried looking and I get what I need to do but to me it seems like the documentation was written by a brain damaged ape, theres barely any explanation for half of what's going on and I'm someone who needs to know why something is working the way it is and why it's written the way it is. I need a video tutorial or something, maybe I'm the brain damaged ape.

Answer (score 0):

i think you maybe use function

```
get_overlapping_bodies()
```

(of Area2D node) for detect another areas or body